# Applescript exec shell script with space in path

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript

The problem I'm trying to solve is to simply run Google Chrome with the --disable-web-security switch in OSX. Since it appears that I cannot add a switch (argument) to an alias I started looking for other options. The suggestion that appeared most often was to use an Applescript and call it from an alias. So I set it up and the script is as follows:

```
do shell script "exec /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOs/Google Chrome --disable-web-security"
```

When I run the script I get the error:

> sh: /Applications/Google: No such file or directory sh: line 0: exec:
>   /Applications/Google: cannot execute: No such file or directory

The script won't process the path past the space in "Google Chrome". How can I modify this script to run with the spaces in the path?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this...

```
set s to "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
do shell script "exec " & quoted form of s & " --disable-web-security"
```